# What to use for navigation: ion-nav or default angular routing?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Can anyone explane me, what should I use for navigation in app? May I only use `ion-nav` etc instead of default angular routing? Isn't it a bad practice? Or maybe there is some combination of using both?

Comment: ionic 3 or Ionic 4?

Comment: @AbuSufian ionic 5

Answer (score 0):

we can use the following HTML to navigate to the detail route.

```
<ion-content class="ion-padding">
  <ion-button [routerLink]="['/detail']">Go to detail</ion-button>
</ion-content>
```

We also can programmatically navigate in our app by using the router API.

```
  navigate(){
    this.router.navigate(['/detail'])
  }
```

Notes: NavController as this is deprecated in IONIC 4 and onwards

Answer (score 0):

You can use LazyLoad which delays the initialization of a resource to improve performance and save system resources.

Example:

```
<ion-button (click)="buttonClicked">Go to Settings</ion-button>
```

and the .ts file

```
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';

constructor ( public navCtrl : NavController ) {}

buttonClicked(){
   this.navCtrl.navigateForward('your-page');
}
```